# Trying to debug .net website with Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I've a working .Net website, I get the code from the server and copy/past it to my computer and it's runing fine on localhost with IIS.

My issue comes when I want to debug it from visual studio. When I run it, it gives an URL like : http://localhost:1390/myWebsitte/Default.aspx or it should be like : http://localhost:1390/Default.aspx. Then the path for css, script and so on are not right any more...

How can I configure my website to get the right URL and be able to debug it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using relative path in your ASP.NET application. Use `~/App_Themes` instead of `/myWebsitte/App_Themes`

Comment: Pleasure helping you. If it solved your problem, Mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `Virtual Path` so it's just `/`.

Comment: That's acutualy the answer I was looking for!